# How to link (not embed) a YouTube video so that it starts in theater mode instead of mini or full screen?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api

Google is filled with answers to "how to modify a youtube link so that it opens in full screen" or "modifying a youtube link to start at a specific time". But how do I modify a link such that it specifically starts with the theater mode?

I am building a chrome extension for my site that detects a click and if the clicked link points to a youtube url, it will opens a mini chrome window (smaller than the main chrome window) that starts playing the video, just like a popup window. Now I don't want to embed the video as embedding has a few restrictions, so I would prefer it this way.

Why do I want theater mode instead of full screen? That's because while on full screen (inside the popped up window) you won't be able to view any comments or other details. Youtube won't let you scroll down while in full screen mode if the url is modified in such a manner.

So how do I achieve this theater mode by editing the link from the beginning?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to keep questions concise and direct. It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's possible there's no such parameter and you'll have to declare/inject a content script that switches to the theater mode explicitly by emitting a `click` event on the button element.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the end of the link:

```
&mode=theatre
```

For instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZsoesa55w&mode=theatre

Comment: Have tried this and it does not seem to work for me - try the link in a new incognito or private window. 

Theatre would also be spelled theater as that is US spelling.